# Knockout component different template - gridstack.js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-components

Following and example from gridstack.js and implemented here:

http://jsfiddle.net/m3qj3qs1/1/

html:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>knockout.js Demo</h1>

        <div>
            <button data-bind="click: add_new_widget">Add new widget</button>
        </div>

        <br>

        <div data-bind="component: {name: 'dashboard-grid', params: $data}"></div>
    </div>



    <template id="gridstack-template">
        <div class="grid-stack" data-bind="foreach: {data: widgets, afterRender: afterAddWidget}">
           <div class="grid-stack-item" data-bind="attr: {'data-gs-x': $data.x, 'data-gs-y': $data.y, 'data-gs-width': $data.width, 'data-gs-height': $data.height, 'data-gs-auto-position': $data.auto_position}">
               <div class="grid-stack-item-content"><button data-bind="click: $root.delete_widget">Delete me</button></div>
           </div></div><!-- <---- NO SPACE BETWEEN THESE CLOSING TAGS -->
    </template>
```

JS:

```
    ko.components.register('dashboard-grid', {
        viewModel: {
            createViewModel: function (controller, componentInfo) {
                var ViewModel = function (controller, componentInfo) {
                    var grid = null;

                    this.widgets = controller.widgets;

                    this.afterAddWidget = function (items) {
                        if (grid == null) {
                            grid = $(componentInfo.element).find('.grid-stack').gridstack({
                                auto: false
                            }).data('gridstack');
                        }

                        var item = _.find(items, function (i) { return i.nodeType == 1 });
                        grid.add_widget(item);
                        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(item, function () {
                            grid.remove_widget(item);
                        });
                    };
                };

                return new ViewModel(controller, componentInfo);
            }
        },
        template: { element: 'gridstack-template' }
    });

    $(function () {
        var Controller = function (widgets) {
            var self = this;

            this.widgets = ko.observableArray(widgets);

            this.add_new_widget = function () {
                this.widgets.push({
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0,
                    width: Math.floor(1 + 3 * Math.random()),
                    height: Math.floor(1 + 3 * Math.random()),
                    auto_position: true
                });
            };

            this.delete_widget = function (item) {
                self.widgets.remove(item);
            };
        };

        var widgets = [
            {x: 0, y: 0, width: 2, height: 2},
            {x: 2, y: 0, width: 4, height: 2},
            {x: 6, y: 0, width: 2, height: 4},
            {x: 1, y: 2, width: 4, height: 2}
        ];

        var controller = new Controller(widgets);
        ko.applyBindings(controller);
    });
```

In the example are 4 widgets loaded (array) and one template defined and a knockout component.

How can I specify different templates for different widgets? Example for each widget one template?

Comment: Quite confusing, each template for each template or ` for each widget one template` ? can you add more details on what are you looking for?

Comment: If you want to go for one template per widget, then you should change your model slightly, at present template is at controller level, it should be moved to `controller.widgets`, it should be a property of `widgets`.

Comment: On the html code there is one template defined `gridstack_template`. Now on the javascript code there is a widgets[] array which contains 4 items, right? Now knockout will use that one single template to render all 4 widgets. My question: how can I bind different template to different widget?

Answer (score 0):

You can use components for widgets as well. Here is a sample how it could look like:

```
<div class="grid-stack-item-content"><div data-bind="component: {name: type, params: $data}"></div></div>
```

And of course your widgets must contain `type`:

```
var widgets = [
    {x: 0, y: 0, width: 2, height: 2, type: 'widgetA'},
    {x: 2, y: 0, width: 4, height: 2, type: 'widgetB'},
    {x: 6, y: 0, width: 2, height: 4, type: 'widgetC'},
    {x: 1, y: 2, width: 4, height: 2, type: 'widgetD'}
];
```

And you need to define these widgets. Please take a look on knockout documentation http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html